# How Can I Make a Bulk insertion with Different Connection in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and I'm Trying To Insert Bulk of data Like this

```
Model::insert($BulkOfData);
```

But My Problem is That I want to Insert These Data With another Connection statically To Be Something Like That

```
Model::setConnection('connection')->insert($BulkOfData);
```

How Can I Do That

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the connection in your Model by adding the `$connection` variable at the top like :

```
protected $connection = 'connection';
```

Then you could use the simple insert :

```
Model::insert($BulkOfData);
```

Else if you want to change the connection on the fly you could use the `on()` method like :

```
Model::on('connection')->insert($BulkOfData);
```

Comment: I have multiple connections depending on the user .. so i cannot set the connection as string like that

Answer (score 1):

setConnection is not a static method.  You can use an instance of the Model:

```
(new Model)->setConnection('connection')->insert(...);
```

Methods like insert can be called statically because they are not defined on Model, so it falls back to the __callStatic logic which calls insert() on the query builder.